# How can I distinguish when 'would' is modal verb or Future in the Past?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, future-in-the-past

In some scientific article I saw this sentence.

> For example, using the vanilla Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance (defined as the minimum number of point changes required to transform a string into another, where a point change is one of the following operations: insertion of a letter, deletion of a letter, and substitution of one letter with another letter) and a threshold δ = 1 , the correction donadl duck → donald duck **would** not **be** possible.

Is 'would be' in this sentence modal verb 'would for conditionals' or 'would for the future in past'? If 'would' is modal verb in this sentence, this sentence is in Present Simple Tense?